# Two tags for matrices

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

At the moment, Computer Science SE has tags [matrices](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/matrices) and [matrix](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/matrix).

1. Shouldn't one be a synonym of the other?
2. Since, on Stack Exchange, [matrices](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/matrices) seems to be more popular<sup>$\star$</sup> than [matrix](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/matrix), I propose that [matrix](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/matrix) be made a synonym of [matrices](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/matrices).

---

$\star$ For example, from my [Filtered Questions](https://stackexchange.com/filters):

[image]

Comment: Good call, thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Back in the day, we decided to use the plural of things as tag. I created a synonym `matrix` → `matrices`.

FWIW, note that every user with sufficient reputation can suggest synonyms:

[image]

You would then have to lobby on Meta or in chat to collect a couple of approval votes. Or have a mod hammer-approve the synonym. :D

Comment: To be clear, mod hammer-approval is indeed what has happened here, and matrix is now a synonym of matrices